# Determine the area of the white, non-shaded parts of the ‘petals’ of a mathematical flower.

Tags: calculus

I haven't been able to figure this one out. In the question, I am asked to determine the area of the white petals of the figure included in the question.

The question itself is included below:

[image]

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_parametric.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

area in polar coordinates:

$\int_a^b \frac 12 r^2 d\theta$

The tough part about this question is what are the limits of integration to get you the white parts and not the grey parts.

The figure has both reflective and rotational symmetry.  Take advantage of that.

$\theta = \frac {\pi}{6}$ is one of the symmetry lines.  Where when $\theta\ge \frac {\pi}{6},$ (but not too much greater) the line segment from $0$ to $r(\theta)$ runs over white petals and not grey.

Next, where does $r(\theta)$ cross $0$?

$\theta = \frac {\pi}{3}$ would be the first crossing of $0.$

$\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac {\pi}{3}} \frac 12 r^2 d\theta$

is the area of $\frac 12$ petal.

And there are $12$ half-petals.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks.

Comment: Ahh, see I didn't know which limits I should use. Thank you so much.